# Integral of second moment

Tags: probability, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-pde, nonlinear-dynamics

I am trying to solve the function

$$\frac{\partial \left \langle f^{2} \right \rangle}{\partial t} = \frac{\left \langle f \right \rangle - \left \langle f^{2} \right \rangle} {N}$$

where $\left \langle f \right \rangle = p$ and $p$ is a real number between 0 and 1.

$\left \langle f \right \rangle$ and $\left \langle f^{2} \right \rangle$ are the first and second moments of the following equation

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \sqrt{\frac{f(1-f)}{N}} \eta (t)$$

where $\eta (t)$ is a Brownian noise term with $\left \langle \eta (t) \right \rangle = 0$ and $\left \langle \eta (t)\eta (t') \right \rangle = \delta(t-t')$ where $\delta$ is a Dirac delta function.

I'm trying to teach myself stochastic processes and performing an integral over the expected value of the second moment is tripping me up.

Advice is appreciated. I did not find a similar question elsewhere on stack-exchang.

Comment: What is $\langle f \rangle$? What relation does $f$ have with $t$ and $N$? Where is the randomness in your equation?

Comment: @Sayantan Thanks for the input. I updated the question to include randomness

Comment: Are you sure that $\langle \eta(t)\rangle =0$ and not $t$ and $\langle \eta(t),\eta(t')\rangle $ is not $t \wedge t'$?